# Editing DB contents

Tags: qgis, table, database

I have loaded polylines from the CSV below:

name;type,status;wkt

01001-4;Integrated;virgin;LINESTRING(xx.x yy.y,xx.x yy.y)

and it populates the table in the DB.

What I would like to do is change the contents of the Status column for any given line to any one of 5 possibilities to reflect the status of that line.
Can I do this from within QGIS or do I need to edit and reload the CSV file each time?
[image: DB Table]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can edit a csv file from within QGIS. Save as a native GIS format (Geopackage or shapefile), then all the editing possibilities, both spatial and attributes, are enabled.